# When a rotating black hole drags spacetime do vacuum particles move with spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, quantum-electrodynamics

Are vacuum fluctuations altered by frame dragging?

Answer (score 0):

They should, but for a solid answer how exactly one would need quantum gravity. But since everything that can't locally exceed the speed of light must corotate at least below the ergosphere, I don't see why vacuum fluctuations should be privileged in that regard since there is no nonrotating flat spacetime background for them to propagate in, although virtual particles are in general not really bound to velocities below c, but that's another story.

Nevertheless, since fluctuations are short lived they won't live long enough to make one revolution, but their average vector should prefer the direction of the rotation, except maybe those time dilated to infinity at the exact horizon, but how exactly one would measure their vectors you'd have to ask a quantum theorist.

Comment: And how would the rotation affect Hawking Radiation?

Comment: All I know about that is that the Hawking radiation would not only reduce the mass but also the angular momentum, and that maximally rotating Kerr black holes (and maximally charged Reissner Nordström ones too) wouldn't radiate at all, but even that is not for sure since Hawking radiation still leads to unsolved problems